# Disable birthdate choice field

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a form with a field for entering birthdate.

```
$builder->add('birthDate', 'birthday', array('label' => 'birthDate', 'translation_domain' => 'messages', 'required' => false, 'widget' => 'choice'))
```

In some cases i want to disable the birhtdate modifications in twig template, like.

```
{{ form_row(form.birthDate.day, {'attr': {'disabled': true}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.birthDate.month, {'attr': {'disabled': true}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.birthDate.year, {'attr': {'disabled': true}}) }}
```

This works fine, but if i render the complete row in one statement like:

```
{{ form_row(form.birthDate, {'attr': {'disabled': true}}) }}
```

This don't disable the birthdate field. Have anyone the same issue?

**I solve my issue**, the problem is that the attributes not injected into `date_widget`

I ovewrite the `date_widget`, now everything is fine.

Before i modify it:

```
{% block date_widget -%}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
        {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
    {% else -%}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-inline')|trim}) -%}
        {% if datetime is not defined or not datetime -%}
            <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') -}}>
        {%- endif %}
        {{- date_pattern|replace({
            '{{ year }}': form_widget(form.year),
            '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month),
            '{{ day }}': form_widget(form.day),
        })|raw -}}
        {% if datetime is not defined or not datetime -%}
            </div>
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock date_widget %}
```

After my modification

```
{% block date_widget -%}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
        {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
    {% else -%}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-inline')|trim}) -%}
        {% if datetime is not defined or not datetime -%}
            <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') -}}>
        {%- endif %}
        {{- date_pattern|replace({
            '{{ year }}': form_widget(form.year, {'attr': attr}),
            '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month, {'attr': attr}),
            '{{ day }}': form_widget(form.day, {'attr': attr}),
        })|raw -}}
        {% if datetime is not defined or not datetime -%}
            </div>
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock date_widget %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not disable it in your template, but when you build your form. (see [birthday form reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html#disabled))

Comment: is disabling on twig not the same logic?

Comment: Absolutly not. In your template, you got view data, generated when you call `$form->createView()` in your controller. I think that function will compute view data base on the form instance options.

Comment: If my answer helped you, can you please validate it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try widget instead of row:

```
{{ form_widget(form.birthDate.day, {'attr': {'disabled': true}}) }}
```